# Do search engines treat the new themed top-level domains the same as historical gTLDs?

Tags: seo, search-engines, search, top-level-domains, search-results

Since the new themed top-level domains (e.g. `.photo`, `.club`) surfaced online, I have rarely seen them in the search results.

I know that some businesses use these new gTLDs, but it seems that everyone, including search engines, prefer the old ones (`.com`, `.net`).

Are there any rules/algorithms that are actually giving less value to these themed top-level domains?

Comment: My first guess would be that these are new or newer domains and do not have the trust metrics or the authority that .com sites have the opportunity to achieve. Add to this, with rarity, these domains will not have SERP impressions, CTR, bounce rates, etc. It may be a bit of an up-hill battle. However, I am sure that Google, at least, will not treat one gTLD differently than another. It is just too much code/work with no gain. I am sure that any of these newer gTLD domains can rank well if enough work is done to ensure it. Cheers!!

Comment: The new top level domains are also not very popular yet, so that is another reason you don't see them in the search results.    I believe that registering domain names for them is usually more expensive than a .com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There are no TLDs that Google finds preferential to others; they are all treated equally in rankings. There are some geo-specific TLDs that Google will default to a specific country and use that as an indicator that the website is more important in a specific geographic region. But all TLDs are treated equally.
>
> Google's systems treat new gTLDs like other gTLDs (like .com and .org). Keywords in a TLD do not give any advantage or disadvantage in search.

**Source:**
http://searchengineland.com/google-explains-how-they-handle-the-new-top-level-domains-tlds-225671